# Access security camera trough my own website, web application developed with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My client want to access their store cameras trough his website, the web application is developed with Laravel, Can anyone guide and help how should I embed their cameras into the website?

Comment: Before posting a question, you should have done the proper research and made attempts to solve your issue yourself. Then, if you get stuck on something _specific_, come back and show us your attempt. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (HTML5) or just the inner object (HTML<5) with all occurences of `%StreamURL%` replaced with the URL of your stream.

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay controls>
    <source src="%StreamURL%" type="video/mp4">
    <object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf" /> 
        <param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip": {"url": "%StreamURL%", "autoPlay":true, "autoBuffering":true}}' /> 
        <p><a href="%StreamURL%">view with external app</a></p> 
    </object>
</video>
```

Comment: is this important that Stream URL should be RTSP protocol? and camera connect to a LAN?